# How to lock ag-grid group header 's children dragging behavior?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

Ag-grid has lockPosition property to change dragging behavior of any column. I have an example ag-grid like below which has two grouped headers and their children underneath:

[image]

I'd like to lock dragging of children columns on each other (Athlete, country) and (Sport, Total, Gold, Silver, Bronze). To do that I set `lockPosition:true` to these children columnDefs.

```
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Athlete Details',
        marryChildren: true,
        children: [
          {
            field: 'athlete',
            lockPosition:true,
            colId: 'athlete',
          },
          {
            field: 'country',
            lockPosition:true,
            colId: 'country',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Sports Results',
        marryChildren: true,
        children: [
          {
            field: 'sport',
            colId: 'sport',
            lockPosition:true
          },
          {
            field: 'total',
            colId: 'total',
                        lockPosition:true
          },
          {
            field: 'gold',
            colId: 'gold',
                        lockPosition:true
          },
          {
            field: 'silver',
            colId: 'silver',
                        lockPosition:true
          },
          {
            field: '

bronze',
        colId: 'bronze',
                    lockPosition:true
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

But grouped headers(Athlete Detals,Sports Results) also affected from this ,instead I want them to be draggable only children should protect their position. How to do that? I've been diving deep ag-grid documentation but couldn't find something useful.

Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/RAftsXt1bJSLsBTj